# Why when generating .app file, xcode needs to be open?

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, xcodebuild

I'm writing a script to build and generate an .app file from an specific target and scheme (to work with simulator). I was using something like:

```
DEVELOPER_DIR=$xcode_app_path/Contents/Developer xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator -scheme "${SCHEME}" -target "${TARGET}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${build_folder}" clean build
```

The problem is, that I need to open XCode for the code above to work, otherwise will show me a message telling me that:

> xcodebuild: error: The project 'Project-name' does not contain a scheme named "${SCHEME}"

I still yet, don't understand what is XCode doing in background. But if I open the IDE and run the script, works. If I open and later close it, and run the script works. It's not working if the project hasn't been opened first with XCode ¬¬

Any suggestion would be appreaciated

Comment: Why You need to open xcode?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude....but, have you read what I wrote? If I don't open Xcode, xcodebuild generates an error...

Comment: Yeah, I read. What is script written in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is facing the same experience, this is what I found out. And works.

Well, apparently **when you create a new scheme through command line**, by default is not **"shared"**. So when you start to link to the folder

```
xcshareddata --> xcschemes
```

(trying to build with command line, for example) there's nothing to link with. Xcode do this automaticaly under the hood when you open your project...

The guys from **CocoaPods** were facing the same issue, so they created a Ruby gem that shares the scheme and place the file in his **xcscheme** folder:

This is the repo: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj

Also, thanks to [this post](http://mgrebenets.github.io/xcode/2014/05/29/share-xcode-schemes/) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368938/xcodebuild-says-does-not-contain-scheme) I found out how to use **xcodeproj** gem, and change the shared option with a script that I put downhere:

```
require 'xcodeproj'
xcproj = Xcodeproj::Project.open("MyProject.xcodeproj")
xcproj.recreate_user_schemes
xcproj.save
```