# error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65

Tags: xcode, react-native

I've build a react-native application and suddenly I get this error message on my terminal during run of the command react-native run-ios.
The same code work fine 10 minutes ago and suddenly I get this error message.
Please help...

Comment: Always be sure to update your Xcode.

Comment: Did you install any new dependencies since it last worked? Have cleaned the build folder and the derived data?

Comment: I have the same issue too, but I don't think XCode version is the problem.

Comment: Did you update react-native version? I had the same problem and I came back to the last RN version.

Comment: I downloaded my react-native version 5 days ago it is 2.0.1 version

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

If you don't have cocoa pods installed you need to `sudo gem install cocoapods`

1. run `cd ios`
2. run `pod install`
3. `cd ..`
4. delete *build* folder
5. run `react-native run-ios`

if the error persists,

1. delete build folder again
2. open the `/ios` folder in x-code
3. navigate File -> Project Settings -> Build System -> change (Shared workspace settings and Per-User workspace settings): Build System ->  Legacy Build System`

You should be good to go.

Comment: hey dude , this one really worked for me!
but u need to change something 
1. cd ios only not cd/ios

Comment: Just removing build folder worked for me. I mean, steps 4 & 5 only.

Comment: Step 2 alone (pod install) did it for me, thanks!

Comment: Where I can find build folder?

Comment: Yep, there is no build folder

Comment: Where is `build` folder ? I'm using Mac 10.15.7 and XCode 11.7

Comment: This doesn't work no more. Actually, if you use the Legacy Build System, the build can't even prepare lol.

Comment: Navigate to `ios` folder and `pod install` works for me.

Comment: If youre on xcode 14 this does not work or exist?

Comment: For those asking, build folder is actually inside the ios folder

Comment: `build` folder is in `ios` folder folks :)

Comment: I don't see it in there, @DanielDanielecki

Comment: It's possible that you don't have a build folder, because your app has never been built for example. In that case, this step is unnecessary.

Comment: @Necmettin Sargın , 
It is in the ios folder, If you have not ran before then you can't see it

Comment: @AliGhafoori thank you Ali but that question was from 2021 :D

Answer (score 41):

1. delete the `build/` folder in `ios/` and rerun
   if that doesn't do any change then
2. File -> Project Settings (or WorkSpace Settings) -> Build System -> Legacy Build System
3. Rerun and voilà!

In case this doesn't work, don't be sad, there is another solution to deeply clean project

1. Delete `ios/` and `android/` folders.
2. Run `react-native eject` [Edit: deprecated, so skip this step]
3. Run `react-native link`
4. `react-native run-ios`

This will bring a whole new resurrection for your project

[Edit] I solved this issue again by removing `Pods` and `build` folders, then running `pod install` in `/ios`.

Comment: I've try 2 times run the same command and now it works.
1) I removed the folder "/ios/build" and rerun.
2) After fail, I changed to Legacy Build System and rerun.
3) After fail, rerun again and voilà! :)

Comment: Thanks! The first solution worked for me. My case was that I moved a react-native project in another folder. That broke the npm run iOS for me.

Comment: @Nagibaba Hi, do i still need to do pod install after resetting using the above method?

Comment: In my case there is no build folder under `iOS/`, please clarify how to get first place

Comment: Then you don't need to remove it :)

Comment: "eject" is deprecated and is no longer a valid command. Please update your answer.

Comment: This is the right answer, and I believe this is needed every single time we update XCode.

Answer (score 36):

**SOLVED:** Always be sure to update your Xcode folks!

**Protip:** And don't do it from the apple store (but always do it from an official apple website of course)

**tip from:** http://ericasadun.com/2016/03/22/xcode-upgrades-lessons-learned/

**official apple download page:** https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

**For those who are unable to resolve with above method**

1. Go to project settings in Xcode. Menu File->Project Settings
2. Go to per-User Project Settings section.
3. Click on advanced.
4. Select Xcode Default option. previously this used to be Legacy for my project.

I have analysed on similar lines and concluded that clean is causing the archive to fail. So, the new build system is not clearing the custom/legacy build directory.

```
delete the build/ folder in ios/ and rerun if that doesn't do any change then
File -> Project Settings (or WorkSpace Settings) -> Build System -> Legacy Build System
Rerun and voilà!
```

If it still Fails you need to clean full project

Do the following:

- Delete ios dir manually
- Clean cache Run `npm cache clean --force`
- Run `react-native eject`
- Re-install all packages `npm install`
- Run the link command `react-native link`
- Finally run `react-native run-ios`

Comment: and what if you are on mid '11 imac and cannot update your Xcode anymore?

Comment: You need to check your react-native version whether it stable to work with xcode version @Angel

Comment: @ToroLoco 

OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 is the last supported release of macOS for your model of iMac. The latest release of Xcode that can be installed on your machine is Xcode 8.2.1 with macOS 10.12.2 SDK and iOS 10.2 SDK.
So update ur imac

Comment: Is up to date, I solve the issue and also post the answer. Going to keep looking with the community is working on a permanent fix

Comment: @Akshay Mulgavkar, the iMac is fully updated but still the error persist. on the 25/03 new xcode came out and my iMac isn't eligible for this update.

Comment: Same problem. '13 iMac and XCode updated to 10.2, but the error persists.

Comment: https://circleci.com/blog/xcodebuild-exit-code-65-what-it-is-and-how-to-solve-for-ios-and-macos-builds/ also follow this whoever has this issue

Comment: React Native 0.61.5. No one of these solutions worked.

Comment: Thank you! Updating the Xcode worked for me. (iPhone running 14.3, but I had to update the Xcode for 14.4, that I kept pending)

Comment: Please clarify; why do I need to always use latest Mac software to get things working ?

I could run Android build without any issue on Android emulator even from 3 year old Mac OS and Android Studio as well.

Comment: some things work and have no valid explanations.

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar Yes! But I'm not complaining ;)

Comment: There is no react-native eject!!!

Comment: How do you get the /ios folder back if you delete it.

Answer (score 30):

`cd ios && rm Podfile.lock && pod install` worked for me.

And perhaps few updates if the first didn't help as much, as:

```sh
sudo gem install cocoapods
rm Podfile.lock && pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me because I deleted the ios directory and checked it back out from git.

Comment: You have to remove Podfile.lock to work the command pod install --repo-update

rm Podfile.lock && pod install --repo-update

Answer (score 17):

After upgrading react-native, you may have stale dependencies. The steps below should fix it.

1. `cd ios`
2. delete Podfile.lock
3. `pod deintegrate && pod install`
4. Navigate back to package.json directory
5. run `react-native run-ios`
6. In Xcode you can build your project again too

I did this after upgrading to `react-native 0.61`

Comment: I keep coming back to this answer. It's been probably my most consistently working fix to various issues I seem to have sometimes. THANK YOU

Comment: This post is what solved it for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 13):

For me it caused by installing react-native-vector-icons and linking by running the `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` command.

I just unlinked the react-native-vector-icons by following commands

1. `react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons`
2. `cd ios`
3. `pod install`
4. `cd ..`
5. `react-native run-ios`

As I already installed an other icon library.

Comment: I had to do `npx react-native unlink react-native vector-icons`

Comment: This was it for me. I had installed vector-icons for adhoc usage. Part of that installation process was to link react-native-vector-icons ... a while later, I wanted to use the react native elements. When I installed native elements and attempted to build the project, the stack trace included information about unlinking vector icons for react native elements to auto build and link it properly.

Comment: thanx bro !!! i had exactly same issue with you and i solved

Comment: I had the same issue and just had to uninstall react-native-vector-icons and it ran without an issue

Answer (score 9):

Should always start with the simplest first, after wasting hours and days on this error.

And after an extensive amount of research,

Simply

```
RESTART YOUR MACHINE
```

This resolved this error.

I'm on

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.63.3
```

Comment: worked for me, thank you for saving my time... and project!!!

Comment: I haven't restarted my computer since installing xcode about a week ago - this solution worked for me

Comment: This simply RESTART YOUR MACHINE save my life !!

Answer (score 8):

This problem may occur after installing react-native-vector-icons

1. Open the project in Xcode.
2. Go to build phases.
3. go to Copy Build resources.
4. Remove all .ttf files from here.
5. Run the application.
   [image]

Comment: You absolute legend, you just saved me potentially hours of time. Thank you!!!

Comment: @kunalNayek it's work for me tnks

Comment: superb! worked for me

Comment: never thought this would work for me. Thank you! this answer needs more votes :)

Answer (score 7):

If you don't have cocoa pods installed you need to:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then run:

```
cd /ios
pod install
```

delete the `build` folder in `ios` folder of your react native project

run:

```
react-native run-ios
```

if error persists:

- delete `build` folder again
- open the `/ios` folder in Xcode
- navigate File -> Project Settings -> Build System -> change (Shared
  workspace settings and Per-User workspace settings): Build System -> Legacy Build System

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, but it was caused by the package manager process port being already used (port 8081).

To fix, I just ran the `react-native` by specifying a different port, see below.

`react-native run-ios --port 8090`

Answer (score 5):

A popular reason to builds failing and error code 65 is a missmatch between cached pod files and current packages used. Here is how to remove the cache and recreate the pods.

**1. Delete Derivate Data -** Remove data that includes cached info of the project Example how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8bTvx0Aoyo

**2. Delete .xcworkspace file from ios folder** - This is the Xcode project file that gets created when you run pod install we want to recreate it in step 4. This project file uses pods and has a white coloured icon instead of the blue coloured base project without pods.

**3. Delete Podfile.lock** - Remove old dependencies info so we can recreate them in the next step.

**Do a pod-install in ios** folder or npx pod-install in root with (React native) - Here we download the pod dependencies again and the pod files only the ones that are used from the current packages are downloaded. A .xcworkspace is regenerated

Comment: Thank you. Worked for me

Comment: My project was initiated from Linux to Mac M1; this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the issue was with my Xcode build scheme. When you run `react-native run-ios` you may see something like,

- info Found Xcode workspace "myproject.xcworkspace"*
- info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace myproject.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme myproject -destination id=xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx -derivedDataPath build/myproject")*

---

In this case, there should be a scheme named ***myproject*** in your ios configurations. The way I fixed it is,

> Double clicked on myproject.xcworkspace in ***ios*** directory (to open workspace with Xcode)
>
> Navigate into *Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes...*
>
> Created a Scheme appropriately with name myproject (this name is case-sensitive)
>
> Ran `react-native run-ios` in project directory

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using a **Mac M1 architecture** it is not directly compatible with Cocoapods. If you encounter issues when installing pods, you can solve it by running:

- sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
- arch -x86_64 pod install

These commands install the ffi package, to load dynamically-linked libraries and let you run the pod install properly, and runs pod install with the proper architecture.

Source: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup see "Note for Mac M1 users"

Answer (score 1):

run pod install inside ios folder then go back to root folder and run npx react-native run-ios

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to rename the project by removing the special characters.

Example: "project_marketplace" to "projectmarketplace"

In this case, I redid the project with react-native init and copied the src and package.json folder.

Answer (score 1):

Some changes in `Podfile` haven't been updated. Maybe one of your native dependencies has changed.

1. `expo prebuild --clean`
2. `cd ios`
3. `pod install`
4. `yarn iOS`

Had the same problem again with the error `No such module 'ExpoModulesCore'`, and the above solution didn't work. This time this code in `Podfile` saved me:

```
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
end
```

found it here https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17511#issuecomment-1128657487

Comment: In my case I did just nee to reinstall my dependencies run `yarn` && `cd ios` && `pod install` thanks.

Comment: It's not strictly true that the AppDelegate.m relies on the Podfile. The podfile specifies the native ios libs to be to be imported for your project. This includes native code that is used by RN Libs that you may be using, and if you are using a hybrid app, native libs that could be used elsewhere in your app. The AppDelegate.m may or may not import these libraries.

Comment: @TMin - edit is gladly welcome!:)

Answer (score 1):

If you encountered issues with **M1**.

Try installing the `ffi` package and running install again.

```sh
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
cd ios
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Another solution that I found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33017#issuecomment-1044059962) works great, basically installing cacoapods with `brew` (and passing `-arm64`).

```sh
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
arch -arm64 brew install cocoapods
cd ios
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've built/run your app previous from Xcode and want to go back to using the terminal you need to clean your build folder.
Go to product -> Clean Build Folder

Answer (score 1):

Earlier the folder name was like :-

```
React Native Projects
```

then I change it to

```
ReactNativeProjects
```

doing this my error was gone because the space was causing problem in the path.

As you can see in the image.

[image]

Comment: yeah, that can be, that can be, also the parent folders too.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be due to having custom named schemes, in that case:

- `cd ios`
- `xcodebuild -list`

Find your's, it might have a -dev suffix. Then:

- `cd ..` (root of the app)
- `npx react-native run-ios --scheme custom-scheme-name`

Answer (score 0):

In my case everything solved after re-cloning the repo and launching it again.

Setup:
Xcode 12.4
Mac M1

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the answers resolved it, since am not able to open .xcworkspace at all. But the legacy comment hinted to a RN to Xcode <> compatibility issue, so i tried all the previous RN Versions and all below RN@0.64 seem to work with xcode 11.3.1
**npx react-native init projectName --version 0.62.0**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below work for me though I encounter error code 65 due to I rename an existing project name to a new name which I did for all the files within the project.
My solution was :-

1. At ios folder level open xworkspace with xcode.
2. Click on file tab then click on workspace settings.
3. I clicked on advance then I select xcode default then I clicked on close button.
4. I clicked on scheme tab which is beside the stop button at the right then I clicked on edit scheme.
5. When the edit scheme opened I clicked on build tab then I click on manage scheme button.
6. I selected scheme of my project name then I clicked the minus(-) button to delete it then I clicked on close
7. I  clicked on clean build folder then when its complete I clicked on build tab to rebuild the project.
8. I clicked on play button which i selected the simulator I want then everything work perfectly again.

Answer (score 0):

I too had an issue with react-native-vector-icons causing this. I still wanted to use the icons though, and I was using VSCode

Workaround was to more or less the same as the manual instructions from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons) but a little different.

1. `npm install --save react-native-vector-icons`
2. copy the .tff files you want to use in node_modules -> react-native-vector-icons -> fonts
3. create a new folder "fonts" in src -> ios
   ...paste the .tff files in there
4. open 'info.plist' in src -> ios -> mobile
5. on the line above `</dict>` paste:

```
<array>
    <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
    <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
    <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Feather.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
    <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
    <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
    <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
  </array>
```

...or whatever fonts you selected.

I ran `react-native run-ios` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In a React Native app, I removed some font assets that I previously linked. For some reason, they didn't get deleted from the Xcode project. I deleted them manually and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For our project, we had to run the `npx react-native link` command in order to get the react native vector icons to show up on Android phones. But that added code to the `ios/yourprojectname.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file.
And that caused the build to fail, throwing an error code 65 and listing out all the fonts that were duplicated.

So, to fix the error, we just removed all of the new code that was added by the `npx react-native link` command.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an issue between different installations of `npm` installed via `nvm` and `homebrew` which somehow messed up my setup.

Building via Xcode usually works without solving the initial problem. I have solved it as follows. Notice, that this guide is suitable if you want to use `nvm`.

First, we remove a possible installation of `npm` and `yarn` using brew as follows.

```bash
brew uninstall npm
brew uninstall yarn
```

We might want to remove nvm as well.

```bash
rm -rf "$NVM_DIR"
```

Next, we reinstall `nvm` by executing the following [command](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

```bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | <ShellOfYourCoice>
```

Replace `<ShellOfYourCoice>` with `bash` if you are using bash, with `zsh` if you are using zsh.

Add the following content to `~/.bash_profile` (.bashrc) for bash or to `~/.zshrc` for zsh (you might need to create these files).

```bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

For zsh, we might need to fix some permissions. Execute the following command.

```bash
compaudit | xargs chmod g-w
```

Then, source the shell of your choice. Verify the installation by executing the following.

```bash
nvm --version
which npm
```

The last command should print something similar to the following.

```bash
/Users/<userName>/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/npm
```

If `yarn` were installed using `npm` previously, we first remove it.

```bash
npm uninstall yarn
```

Next, we reinstall it.

```bash
npm i -g yarn
```

These steps fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS, make sure that none of the names of the directories has a space character `' '` in their names. I spent hours figuring out the problem and the problem was so small.

Answer (score 0):

***error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65***
That was my error and i resolve this error with the following commands:-

1- Uninstall Ruby with: **brew uninstall ruby --force**

2-Uninstall CocoaPods. At first, try to list all CocoaPods versions / components with **gem list --local | grep cocoapods**. Then uninstall them one by one, in my case:

1- **sudo gem uninstall cocoapods**

2- **sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core**

3- **sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
,cocoapods-plugins
,cocoapods-search
,cocoapods-trunk
,cocoapods-try**

etc.

3- As a next step I was able to reinstall ffi and then CocoaPods with:
i) **sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi**
ii) **sudo arch -x86_64 gem install cocoapods**

Once done, I could run **pod install** as expected. Note that I had the Terminal open all the time in standard mode - no Rosetta required.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and tried to change the name of the TestApp-folder. Notice the last line in the warning:

> xcodebuild: error: The workspace named "TestApp2" does not contain a
> scheme named "TestApp-tvOS". The "-list" option can be used to find
> the names of the schemes in the workspace.

Not changing the TestApp name in the command nor after from this, helped me get rid of the message and the app was built:

```
react-native init TestApp --version=react-native@npm:react-native-tvos@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

If you are experiencing this in 2023 because you updated your Xcode to version 15, simply upgrade your react native to version 0.71.11 and above.

See more info [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.71.11). Same goes for expo projects (see [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22832)).

If you don't want to upgrade your react native version, there is a workaround described [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37748#issuecomment-1580589448).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For me this error showed up after upgrading React Native from 0.69 to 0.72.

Suprisingly all that was needed was to:

**Remove all the derived data and rebuild**:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && npx react-native run-ios`

If still doesn't work then

**1. Make sure metro server is stopped and run a full cache clean**:

`watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod install && cd .. && npx react-native run-ios`

Note: if pod install fails take a deep looks at the pod errors

**2. Attempt to build with Xcode and look deep into any errors triggered at  Xcode build process**

Answer (score -1):

there was some issue while creating the app
so in my case i just deleted the `package-lock.json` and did `npm i`

after that

`cd ios/` and `pod install`

Comment: deleting `package-lock` or `yarn.lock` is not recommended. Mere `rm-rf node_modules` then `npm i` or `yarn` might be enough

Answer (score -4):

Here is the a possible solution

[The problem is found in RealmReact.xcodeproj](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/2305#issuecomment-476561324)

Comment: Share the answer here, not a link

Comment: This problem is solved by selecting "Team name"  From "signing & capabilities" in XCODE. Try this once