# React-native -run-ios error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65

Tags: react-native

good time.
run ios error Failed

run code
react-native run-ios

error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening reactapp.xcodeproj

** BUILD FAILED **[image]

Comment: have you tried it building using Xcode?

Comment: no  sanjaykmwt     code react-native run-ios

Comment: try building using xcode

Comment: Same problem but no solution. Have you got the answer?

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got the same error when run

> $ react-native run-ios

My workaround steps:

1. open project by Xcode and choose the signature information as the attached image.
2. clear build folder: 'Your Project'/ios/build
3. re-run:

> $ react-native run-ios

Hope this help.

Comment: 'Your Project'/ios/build doesn't exist? Here is everything inside ios:

Podfile, helloWorld, helloWorld.xcodeproj, Podfile.lock, helloWorld-tvOS, helloWorld.xcworkspace, Pods, helloWorld-tvOSTests, helloWorldTests

Comment: Me too, no build exist anymore

Answer (score 3):

That's because there is a new version of Flipper and React Native might not come with the right one so best is to go in your podfile and add this use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.74.0' }) then run pod install

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have cocoa pods installed you need to by command `sudo gem install cocoapods` and run following commands from your project main directory

```
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
```

delete build folder from ios

```
react-native run-ios
```

if error persists, 1. delete build folder again 2. open the `/ios` folder in x-code 3. navigate File -> Project Settings -> Build System -> change (Shared workspace settings and Per-User workspace settings): Build System -> Legacy Build System

Answer (score 0):

cd ios

rm -rf build/

cd ..

react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

For me this error showed up after upgrading React Native from 0.69 to 0.72.

Suprisingly all that was needed was to:

**Remove all the derived data and rebuild:**

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && npx react-native run-ios`

If still doesn't work then

**1. Make sure metro server is stopped and run a full cache clean:**

`watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod install && cd .. && npx react-native run-ios`

Note: if pod install fails take a deep looks at the pod errors

**2. Attempt to build with Xcode and look deep into any errors triggered at Xcode build process**

Additional notes:
this question is possibly a duplicate of [error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235825/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit)