# ReactNative First Project create, but not able to build and run the project

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, xcode10.1

Here I mention my ReactNative environment Information:

```
info 
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.5
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4278U CPU @ 2.60GHz
      Memory: 96.07 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
    IDEs:
      Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3 
      react-native: 0.59.9 => 0.59.9 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

And all setup are done (I follow this [Tutorial](https://medium.com/@randerson112358/setup-react-native-environment-for-ios-97bf7faadf77)) but when I fire the

`react-native run-io`

Than terminal show me the error..
[image]

I already Perform below settings.. (As per the given [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235825/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit))

```
Go to project settings in Xcode. Menu File->Project Settings

Go to per-User Project Settings section.

Click on advanced.

Select Xcode Default option. previously this used to be Legacy for my project.
```

I'm newbies in ReactNative. Please help me..

Comment: perhaps you can take a look at this [fix](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24990#issuecomment-495493250).

Comment: @kenmistry I'm newbies so I don't know how to perform that operation which are mention in your link

Comment: I tried with this command but not work.
$ cd node_modules/react-native/scripts && ./ios-install-third-party.sh && cd ../../../
$ cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/ && ../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh && cd ../../../../