# App not building after installing react-native-webrtc

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods

My react native app build when i do run-ios, but after installing webrtc with this command:

```
npm install react-native-webrtc --save
```

i get this error:

```
error failed to build ios project. we ran xcodebuild command but it exited with error code 65
```

i tried every on this solution:[error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235825/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit/55235914)
 nothing worked

any one have any ide how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If react-native > 0.60 then do this

npm install react-native-webrtc --save
open xcode and do same as step 1 from doc

https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/blob/master/Documentation/iOSInstallation.md

skip step 2,3,4 
direct go to step 5 and add permissons.
and Done its work for me.