# I created new React-Native project, but its not running on my iOS simulator and getting this error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcodebuild

i am installing new react native project, but its not running on my IOS simulator.

```
 error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening AwsomeProject.xcworkspace.  Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace AwsomeProject.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme AwsomeProject -destination id=25C3F1EC-B34C-44CA-91A2-C595FEE2FAB7
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235825/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit]

Comment: @Rohit react-native eject is not working now, whats the alternative of eject?