# Error: Redefinition of module 'fmt' & 'folly'

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-cli

Im trying build my react native app with cli and this error log appear. Xcode builds are solid and no error occurs.

Here is part of log:

```
2 errors generated.
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
While building module 'Darwin' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
In file included from <module-includes>:23:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/stdatomic.h:24:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/stddef.h:102:10: fatal error: could not build module '_Builtin_stddef_max_align_t'
#include "__stddef_max_align_t.h"
 ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
5 errors generated.
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <sys/types.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
While building module 'ptrauth' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:717:
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/fmt.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'fmt'
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/Flipper-Fmt.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/RCT-Folly.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'folly'
module folly {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/Flipper-Folly.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module folly {
       ^
2 errors generated.
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/fmt.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'fmt'
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/Flipper-Fmt.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/RCT-Folly.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'folly'
module folly {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/Flipper-Folly.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module folly {
       ^
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
While building module 'Dispatch' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:20:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:25:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <Availability.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
While building module 'Dispatch' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:20:
While building module 'os_object' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:63:
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/fmt.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'fmt'
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/Flipper-Fmt.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/RCT-Folly.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'folly'
module folly {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/Flipper-Folly.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module folly {
       ^
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
While building module 'Dispatch' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:20:
While building module 'os_object' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:63:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/usr/include/os/object.h:25:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <Availability.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
3 errors generated.
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
While building module 'Dispatch' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:20:
While building module 'os_workgroup' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:64:
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/fmt.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'fmt'
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/Flipper-Fmt.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/RCT-Folly.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'folly'
module folly {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/Flipper-Folly.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module folly {
       ^
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
While building module 'Dispatch' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:20:
While building module 'os_workgroup' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:64:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/usr/include/os/workgroup.h:29:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/usr/include/os/workgroup_base.h:8:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <sys/types.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
3 errors generated.
9 errors generated.
19 errors generated.
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: fatal error: could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'ObjectiveC' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:6:
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/fmt.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'fmt'
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/Flipper-Fmt.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/RCT-Folly.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'folly'
module folly {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/Flipper-Folly.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module folly {
       ^
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'ObjectiveC' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:6:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/usr/include/objc/./NSObjCRuntime.h:8:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
3 errors generated.
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'Security' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:9:
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/fmt.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'fmt'
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/Flipper-Fmt.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/RCT-Folly.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'folly'
module folly {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/Flipper-Folly.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module folly {
       ^
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'Security' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLCredential.h:9:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:27:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h:27:10: fatal error: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
3 errors generated.
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'CoreServices' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLError.h:15:
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/fmt.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'fmt'
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/fmt/Flipper-Fmt.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module fmt {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/RCT-Folly.modulemap:1:8: error: redefinition of module 'folly'
module folly {
       ^
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/folly/Flipper-Folly.modulemap:1:8: note: previously defined here
module folly {
       ^
While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:
While building module 'CoreServices' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLError.h:15:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:9:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/UTCoreTypes.h:19:10: fatal error: could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
3 errors generated.
31 errors generated.
/Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m:1:9: fatal error: could not build module 'Foundation'
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~^
34 errors generated.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/build/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.o /Users/omerkocer/tekvetek/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension-dummy.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Pods-tekvetek_RN-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

Tried this solutions but they are not worked for my case:

**1.**

- pod deintegrate
- pod install

**2.**

- **Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules** to **YES** in Build Settings tab.

**3.**

- Delete all cached pods & pod install again.

Comment: siga os passos descritos nesse link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235825/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error after enabling `use_modular_headers!` in my pod file, it was needed by a few of my pods, causing the `no module found` error. As a result, instead of enabling modular headers for every pod, I switched it only for specific:

1. Disable `use_modular_headers!`
2. Add `:modular_headers => true` to each pod that needs it

```
pod 'POD_NAME', 'x.x.x', :modular_headers => true
```