# Failed building - Building app with Xcode.app, by opening .xcworkspace file

Tags: xcode, react-native, webstorm

I have fixed a number of errors that occurred. I have now got CocoaPods to work properly. When I then run the program again, I get over 20+ building apps messages. After some time, I get the following error:

```
Building the app....
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening MyApp.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme MyApp -destination id
User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
```

I'm using Webstorm and Xcode (simulator), getting the same problem on both Webstorm and Xcode.

```text
Version 14.3.1 (994)
SimulatorKit 629
CoreSimulator 920.3
```

I've followed lots of solutions here, I did follow all of their solutions[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235825/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit/55235914#55235914)
As the title say how do I build my app with the -xcworkspace file? I've tried to open the app with the .xcworkspace file, but it doesn't work. How should I handle the .xcworkspace file?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could maybe come in handy. Take a look at this thread, it describes the same problem you have.

- [Exited with error code 65](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235825/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit)

Asnwer from that thread

1. run `cd ios`
2. run `pod install`
3. `cd ..`
4. delete build folder
5. run `react-native run-ios`

if the error persists,

1. delete `build folder` again
2. open the /ios folder in x-code
3. navigate File -> Project Settings -> Build System -> change (Shared
   workspace settings and Per-User workspace settings): Build System ->
   Legacy Build System`

Comment: Thanks for your time. As mentioned in the question, I've followed all of the solutions multiple times - still no luck.