# When i run react native ios I'm getting this error

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I try to  npx react-native run-ios  i is not running and it’s showing this error
How can I solve this problem

```
    error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening test.xcworkspace.
    Command line invocation:
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace test.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme test -destination id=8E4F9416-0C08-4ACA-B41D-D950C2208A66
    
    User defaults from command line:
        IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
    
    Prepare packages


........

    
    Computing target dependency graph and provisioning inputs   
    
     The following build commands failed:
            PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/mohammedsuja/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-eabnxomykigrnaepxsyqxilqoeiw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-rncore.build/Script-46EB2E00018190.sh (in target 'React-rncore' from project 'Pods')
        (1 failure)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235825/error-failed-to-build-ios-project-we-ran-xcodebuild-command-but-it-exited-wit)