# Commit localizable.strings to the repository

Tags: ios, git, localization, gitlab, localizable.strings

I need to add some more languages to the project. 
Manually i go to the Info of a project where i would add as many languages as i would like to.
Then the Xcode would ask which files to localize for the chosen language. So let's say we have one more **localizable.strings** created for the new language just added.
Which files should i send to the repository (currently using gitlab) to let the project understand the new language has been added?
Guess it is not enough to just send new **localizable.strings** located in "**new_language.Iproj**" folder to the server. 

Which file does contain this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are right! The sufficient files are those in new directory `new_language.lproj`. You will also need to commit your `PROJECT-NAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` for Xcode to recognize that new language was added.

Comment: So the project.pbxproj from `PROJECT-NAME.xcodeproj` and `new_language.lproj` containing respective `localizable.strings` will be enough?

Comment: What a nice program:)

Comment: Guess we missed shared schemes. It asks new shared schemes also while building the app. Just in case someone needs it i will put this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368938/xcodebuild-says-does-not-contain-scheme . I needed to upload shared scheme after received: "no shared schemes found for your project", "Automatically generated schemes may differ from the ones in your project", "Make sure to share your schemes for the expected behaviour". This happened after i have changed the language to test new localization.