# xcodebuild failing on teamcity build agent: scheme is not currently configured for the test action

Tags: xcode, macos, vmware, xcodebuild

The tests run fine both inside XCode and at the command line on my Mac. Inside the TeamCity build agent (running in VMWare on a Mac mini), the test also pass when run inside XCOde. But at the command line, I get the message "scheme ___ is not currently configured for the test action". I know that having XCode running can mess up the command line build, so I have it closed. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Ironically, I tried it with XCode open and then it worked. Closed XCode and it still worked. But when I retried it from TeamCity, it still fails. Must be some kind of transient setting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the scheme was not shared. More information here: [xcodebuild says does not contain scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368938/xcodebuild-says-does-not-contain-scheme). (Ignore the statement that this will only solve the problem if you are building a workspace. I was building a project, but making the scheme Shared and then checking in the file that Xcode created fixed the problem.