# Build in xcode via terminal, using the "build for profiler" settings

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

Is there a way to specify to xcodebuild, to build a specific scheme/configuration?

I have a project with multiple related projects; and when I want to build all, I just run it with "build for profiler", and it takes care to grab the right code, the right related projects in the solution and give me the resulting products compiled, and ready to be tested.

I am trying to automate the process, so I can run it via console; altho I've found no documentation that specify how to build for specific settings that you have in Xcode UI, but using the console version (xcodebuild).

I can build each project separately, and put all together by hand, but it is laborious and error prone; I would rather go for what Xcode does, but without using the UI at all.

Not even sure if it is possible; any pointer is more than welcome. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example:

```
$ xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -alltargets -configuration Release
```

You can get the full documentation in the terminal with this command:

```
$ man xcodebuild
```

There is also an article here: http://blog.octo.com/en/automating-over-the-air-deployment-for-iphone/

Comment: I see, so the flag -alltargets will basically build all that is in the configuration for "build for profiler" ? Thanks!

Comment: I think you may be confusing build configurations with schemes. The command above will use Release build settings to build all targets defined in the project. If you want to execute a scheme, you need to specify its name:

    $ xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -scheme "Scheme Name"

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can run the profiler via the terminal. The supported build actions are: build archive test install installsrc clean

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that; the point was to obtain all that I get, when I run the Xcode command "build for profiler". I use a command line version of the static analyzer, so I do 't really use Instruments at all. I can just write a script in sh that will build piece by piece every project and related projects for now; -alltarget didn't build all the related projects, only the ones present inside the main project. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to build a `.xcworkspace` use

`xcodebuild -workspace your_project.xcworkspace -scheme your_sheme`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5304206/4420355) is a description where you find your scheme.

Tldr: left click on your project (red arrow) -> manage scheme -> use the selected one

[image]